# Is sequence length and hidden size is the same in Transformer

Tags: lstm, pytorch, transformer

I'm confused about sequence length and hidden size if they are the same in Transformer.
I think they are different but not sure.

```
class Embeddings(nn.Module):
    """Construct the embeddings from patch, position embeddings.
    """
    def __init__(self, config, img_size, in_channels=3):
        super(Embeddings, self).__init__()
        self.hybrid = None
        self.config = config
        img_size = _pair(img_size)
        b_size=16 
        if config.patches.get("grid") is not None:   # ResNet
            grid_size = config.patches["grid"]
            patch_size = (img_size[0] // b_size // grid_size[0], img_size[1] // b_size // grid_size[1])
            patch_size_real = (patch_size[0] * b_size, patch_size[1] * b_size)
            n_patches = (img_size[0] // patch_size_real[0]) * (img_size[1] // patch_size_real[1])  
            self.hybrid = True
        else:
            patch_size = _pair(config.patches["size"])
            n_patches = (img_size[0] // patch_size[0]) * (img_size[1] // patch_size[1])
            self.hybrid = False

        if self.hybrid:
            self.hybrid_model = ResNetV2(block_units=config.resnet.num_layers, width_factor=config.resnet.width_factor)
            in_channels = self.hybrid_model.width * 16
        self.patch_embeddings = Conv2d(in_channels=in_channels,
                                       out_channels=config.hidden_size,
                                       kernel_size=patch_size,
                                       stride=patch_size)
        print("config.hidden_size",config.hidden_size)
        print("n_patches",n_patches)
        self.position_embeddings = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1, n_patches, config.hidden_size))

        self.dropout = Dropout(config.transformer["dropout_rate"])


    def forward(self, x):
        
        if self.hybrid:
            x, features = self.hybrid_model(x)
        else:
            features = None
           
        x = self.patch_embeddings(x)  # (B, hidden. n_patches^(1/2), n_patches^(1/2))
        x = x.flatten(2)
        x = x.transpose(-1, -2)  # (B, n_patches, hidden)

        embeddings = x + self.position_embeddings
        embeddings = self.dropout(embeddings)
        return embeddings, features
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No they are quite different. The sequence length is the number of tokens that are processed by the transformer together. Each token could be a word embedding, character embedding or some other chunk of natural language encoded into numbers, like pairs of consecutive bytes in byte pair encoding(BPE<sup>[1](https://huggingface.co/learn/nlp-course/chapter6/5?fw=pt)</sup>). The sequence length thus determines the span of text that the model looks at, at once.

The hidden state is a representation generated by the model for every token taking into account the token itself and the tokens present around it (up to sequence length). The representation is typically a small vector of size 32 or 64 etc.

For example if we have sequence length of five(word tokens) and we have the following, suitably preprocessed, English sentence:

> [START]Is[SPACE]sequence[SPACE]length[SPACE]and[SPACE]hidden[SPACE]size[SPACE]is[SPACE]the[SPACE]same[SPACE]in[SPACE]Transformer[END]

The 5 word sequence [START]Is[SPACE]sequence[SPACE] will be fed to the model that will generate one hidden state vector for each of the tokens it sees. So a total of five vectors each of some predetermined `hidden_state_size` get generated.

Note that in practice each word in the sequence is encoded using an embedding of some sort so [START]Is[SPACE]sequence[SPACE] will be a list/array of five embedding vectors.